# Java simplifying repetitive code involving boolean comparison

Tags: java, simplify

I am trying to find a way to reduce the length and simplify the following repetitive methods :

```
boolean circleFlag, squareFlag, diamondFlag;

public void shapeButtonPressed(String shapeType) {

    if (shapeType.equals("Circle")) {
        circlePressed();
    } else if (shapeType.equals("Square")) {
        squarePressed();
    } else if (shapeType.equals("Diamond")) {
        diamondPressed();   
    }

}

public void circlePressed() {
    if(!circleFlag){
        //set only circleFlag true and the rest false.
        circleFlag = true;
        squareFlag = false;
        diamondFlag = false;

        //(... some code)
    } else {
        //set all flags false.
        circleFlag = false; 
        diamondFlag = false
        squareFlag = false;

        //(... some different code)
    }

}
public void squarePressed() {
    if(!squareFlag){
        //set only squareFlag true and the rest false.
        squareFlag = true;
        circleFlag = false;
        diamondFlag = false;

        //(... some code)
    } else {
        //set all flags false.
        circleFlag = false; 
        diamondFlag = false
        squareFlag = false;

        //(... some different code)
    }

}
public void diamondPressed() {
    if(!diamondFlag){
        //set only diamondFlag true and the rest false.
        diamondFlag = true;
        squareFlag = false;
        circleFlag = false;

        //(... some code)
    } else {
        //set all flags false.
        circleFlag = false; 
        diamondFlag = false
        squareFlag = false;

        //(... some different code)
    }
}
```

---

### Things I have tried

I have tried to set all my values to `Boolean` type, set them in a `ArrayList<Boolean>` and change the `shapePressed(String shapeType)` method to

```
public void shapePressed(String shapeType) {

    Boolean currFlag = false;

    if (shapeType.equals("Circle")) {
        currFlag = circleFlag;
    } else if (shapeType.equals("Square")) {
        currFlag = squareFlag;
    } else if (shapeType.equals("Diamond")) {
        currFlag = diamondFlag;
    }

    if (!currFlag){
        for (Boolean flag : shapeFlag) flag = ( flag == currFlag ) ? true : false; 

        //(...)
    } else {
        for (Boolean flag : shapeFlag) flag = false;

        //(...)
    }
}
```

but the line `( flag == currFlag )` compares the booleans as values and not as individual objects. So my `currFlag` is pointless in this above method.

I then though of using a `HashMap<String ,Boolean>` but whenever I compare the values given a key (String shapeType from the method parameter), I encounter the same problem as above.

What is a way to simplify this code ?

Comment: Instead of `if (circleFlag) { ...}` you could just do `circleFlag = !circleFlag;` and then set the other flags to false.

Comment: There's probably a ton of ways to accomplish this, but I might suggest using an [Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) to represent your different shapes and store a `currFlag` of that Enum type which represents the current shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a given shape is activated, you just invert that flag. Then the other flags get set to false.

So, trivially, you could simplify your `circlePressed()` logic to:

```
public void circlePressed() {
    circleFlag = !circleFlag;
    squareFlag = false;
    diamondFlag = false;

}
```

Of course there's still a lot of repetition. You could refactor this further to an enum and track the state there.

```
public enum Flag {
  CIRCLE( false ),
  SQUARE( false ),
  DIAMOND( false ); // default state is false for all

  private boolean state;
  private Flag(boolean state) {
    this.state = state;
  }

  public void flipState() {
    this.state = !this.state;
  }

  public void setState(boolean state) {
    this.state = state;
  }
}

// notice this method takes the Flag not a string
public void shapeButtonPressed(Flag selected) {

    // iterate through all the flags ...
    for( Flag flag : Flag.values() ) {
        if (flag == selected) {
            // invert the "pressed" flag state
            flag.flipState();
        } else {
            // ... and set the rest to false
            flag.setState(false);
        }
    }
}
```

The built-in `values` method on enums returns a list of all of the defined enums, so we can just iterate across them.

It's a bit gimmicky, I admit, since it's not really what enums are intended for, but it simplifies your logic quite a bit.

Comment: I don't quite see the point of tracking state in three variables to begin with, if only one can ever be true at the same time.

Comment: An `activeState` variable might make sense but unfortunately we don't know much around the use cases surrounding the code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an enum.

```
public enum Shape {
  CIRCLE, SQUARE, DIAMOND
}
```

Then, use that in your code like so;

```
Shape shape;

public void shapeButtonPressed(Shape selectedShape) {
    shape = selectedShape;
}
```

If you can't change the method signature of `shapeButtonPressed` and it has to take a String, you can stil do

```
Shape shape;

public void shapeButtonPressed(String shapeType) {
    if (shapeType.equals("Circle")) {
        shape = Shape.CIRCLE;
    } else if (shapeType.equals("Square")) {
        shape = Shape.SQUARE;
    } else if (shapeType.equals("Diamond")) {
        shape = Shape.DIAMOND;
    }

}
```

Comment: A cleverer selection of the correct enum instead of a chain of `if` can be written. You could select based on its name, for example. You could also introduce a static function within the enum class that does the mapping for you. This is just a proof of concept, not exactly the most elaborate way to solve it.

Comment: If the OP needs to be able to "unselect" a Shape when the same shape button is pressed, the code could also be trivially modified to set the `shape = null` when `shape == shapeType` to represent no selection.

Comment: @JohannesH. Thank you, I forgot about enums. But, later in my code, in other methods, I sometimes have something like `if(circleFlag || squareFlag || diamondFlag) { //(...) }`. Does this mean I can't use the method you have provided ?

Comment: You just have to change the code. You could do either `if (shape == Shape.SQUARE || shape == Shape.DIAMOND || shape == Shape.CIRCLE) {...}` or, if there aren't more the those three shapes, just use `if (shape != null) {...}`

Comment: @JohannesH Oh right that's awesome ! Thank you so much for your help :).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to my approach with enums above (that I highly recommend over this one), you can do a more "C-style" solution using a bitmask instead of boolean flags.

A bitmask is essentially a numeric (or binary for that matter) value of which each bit represents a boolean value.

```
int shapeFlags;

public void shapeButtonPressed(String shapeType) {
    if (shapeType.equals("Circle")) {
        shapeFlags = 1;
    } else if (shapeType.equals("Square")) {
        shapeFlags = 2;
    } else if (shapeType.equals("Diamond")) {
        shapeFlags = 4;
    }
}
```

This still leaves you the option to set more than one shape to `true` while being able to override all flags in a single operation.

Mappings from numeric values to shapes would look like this:

```
0 : no shape
1 : circle
2 : square
3 : circle & square
4 : diamond
5 : diamond & circle
6 : diamond & square
7 : all three
```